# Click on one element from table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a table by address `//*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody`
Strings of this table have following addresses

```
//*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]
```

`//*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]` etc.

Each string have some fields with address

```
//*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
                                                        /td[2] etc.
```

For example if I should find some text by address in  /`/*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]` and click on this element what options do I have?

I tried to use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]').click()
```

or

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/*[@id="offence-list-grid"]/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody')
    for item in table:
        if item.text == 'my_text':
            item.click()
```

But it does not lead to success.

Web page

```
<div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable" data-role="virtualscrollable" style="width: 1161px; overflow: hidden; padding-right: 18px; height: 789px;"><div class="k-virtual-scrollable-wrap"><table role="grid" style="width: 3520px; touch-action: pan-y;" data-role="selectable" class="k-selectable"><colgroup><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:110px"><col style="width:180px"><col style="width:100px"><col style="width:400px"><col style="width:150px"><col style="width:350px"><col style="width:180px"><col style="width:140px"><col style="width:350px"><col style="width:150px"><col style="width:150px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:160px"><col style="width:140px"></colgroup><tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="1051d46e-b0fd-421e-b4ba-944b17169c9a" role="row" style="height: 55px;"><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 14.03.2018 19:02:31</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 8102УУ9</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class="">  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 12.9ч.3</span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> Брак(Не найдено ТС) </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> р-н Атюрьевский р-н, г Рузаевка, ул Полевая </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> Поток-ПДД ПОТОК-ПДД R27 </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> ЦАФАП ОДД ГИБДД МВД по Республике Мордовия</span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class="">    </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class="">    </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 13.03.2018 14:16</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"></td></tr><tr class="k-alt" data-uid="d75d069f-d760-4b71-b345-97558c007ee1" role="row" style="height: 55px;"><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 14.03.2018 19:01:41</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 8102УУ9</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class="">  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 12.9ч.3</span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> Брак(Не найдено ТС) </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> р-н Атюрьевский р-н, г Рузаевка, ул Полевая </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> Поток-ПДД ПОТОК-ПДД R28 </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"></td><td role="gridcell"><span class=""> ЦАФАП ОДД ГИБДД МВД по Республике Мордовия</span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class="">    </span></td><td role="gridcell"><span class="">    </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class=""> 13.03.2018 14:02</span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span>  </span></td><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"></td></tr><tr data-uid="bafca0e2-bce3-4ca9-93e6-bcc83e98fa80" role="row" style="height: 55px;"><td class="ui-grid-column-centered" role="gridcell"><span class="">
```

Comment: Instead of breaking up the _HTML_ `<tags>` update the question with relevant text based formatted _HTML_ for proper analysis.

Comment: if it is a link with `a` tag, you can use `find_element_by_link_text`. please post the HTML part of the address you want to click

Comment: Yes, sure, I added a part of webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand the reason of this behavior, but found solution :)

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#offence-list-grid > div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable > div.k-virtual-scrollable-wrap > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)